# Unlink BlueSoleil and Skype

Tags: skype, bluetooth

For some reason `BlueSoleil` and `Skype` are somehow linked. If I open `Skype` it also opens automatically `BlueSoleil` and even if I close it manually, it opens it again.

I disabled `1Support VoIP` but it still does this. I want to use these softwares completely separate. I can open the other for myself if I want it.

How can I stop them doing this?